# python: pickle object with a user defined class name and path

Tags: python, serialization, type-conversion, deserialization, pickle

Here is the problem: I have a set of pickle files with objects and it takes large computing time (like ~2 months) to recreate those objects. I need to convert those objects (`class A` stored in file `Av1.py`) into a new class (`class A` stored in file `Av2.py`) objects but save them such that during loading pickle would search for `class A` in `Av1.py` such that later I could just rename `Av2.py => Av1.py` and have the new objects interpreted as having type of `class A` stored in the original file `Av1.py`. How can I do it?

Here is an example:

```py
# Av1.py
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
```

```py
# Av2.py
class A:
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y
```

```py
# python session 1
from Av1 import A as Av1
from Av2 import A as Av2

def convert(av1): return Av2(av1.x+1)

av1 = Av1(1)
av2 = convert(av1)

import pickle, gzip
with gzip.open('o.gzpkl', 'wb', compresslevel=9) as f:
    pickle.dump(av2, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

```bsh
mv Av2.py Av1.py # Linux shell command to rename file Av2.py into Av1.py
```

```py
# python session 2
import pickle, gzip
with gzip.open('o.gzpkl', 'rb') as f:
    av = pickle.load(f)
```

Expected result: `python session 1` is modified such that `python session 2` works and interprets the object in `o.gzpkl` as having type `Av1.A`.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution: I need to do the following before writing `av2`

```py
av2.__class__ = Av1
```

i.e. `python session 1` should be

```py
from Av1 import A as Av1
from Av2 import A as Av2

def convert(av1): return Av2(av1.x+1)

av1 = Av1(1)
av2 = convert(av1)

av2.__class__ = Av1 # solution !!!!

import pickle, gzip
with gzip.open('o.gzpkl', 'wb', compresslevel=9) as f:
    pickle.dump(av2, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```